# OnPlatform in xamarin forms for input transparent property

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I want input transperant to be true for ios and false for android i tried  OnPlatform but i could not make it work

```
<PopupPage.InputTransparent>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="false">
                    <OnPlatform.iOS>false</OnPlatform.iOS>
                    <OnPlatform.Android>true</OnPlatform.Android>
                </OnPlatform>
    </PopupPage.InputTransparent>
```

I am wondering what should i give in this place

```
 <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="false">
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Please consider marking as answer/upvoting if an answer helped you.

Answer (score 3):

The `TypeArguments` needs the type of the argument you're giving in the platform specific parts. Xamarin wants to know what the string value of "false" or "true" should be casted too. In this case that's a `Boolean` which means you should put down `x:Boolean` as the value.

```
<PopupPage.InputTransparent>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean">
        <OnPlatform.iOS>false</OnPlatform.iOS>
        <OnPlatform.Android>true</OnPlatform.Android>
    </OnPlatform>
</PopupPage.InputTransparent>
```

The "x:" part refers back to the namespace defined at the top of your XAML file:

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with OnPlatform but with OnIdiom at Typeargument you say which type your variabel is. For instance here for you it is Boolean

so try this:

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean">
```

Let me know if it works